# Combine two Arrays with Common and Extra Elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have two arrays as following

```
  firstArray={1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,11} ;
  secondArray={1,2,3,4,7,8,10} ;
```

from these two arrays i need to get resultant Array as :

```
  resultant ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
```

How can i Achieve this.
 Any Suggestions Please.

Comment: Just a remark: what you call Common and Extra elements is officially called a [Union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)).

Answer (score 4):

There are so many ways to do :

**You need to sort the array once two are merged, so as to produce the desired result**

Starting with the basic way :

```
NSArray *firstArray=@[@1,@2,@3,@5,@6,@8,@9,@10,@11];
NSArray *secondArray=@[@1,@2,@3,@4,@7,@8,@10];

NSMutableArray *merged=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:firstArray];
for (id element in secondArray) {
    if (![merged containsObject:element]) {
        [merged addObject:element];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Merged %@",merged);
```

---

Using `Set`

```
NSSet *firstSet=[NSSet setWithArray:firstArray];
NSSet *secondSet=[NSSet setWithArray:secondArray];

NSMutableSet *unionFirstSecondSet=[NSMutableSet new];
[unionFirstSecondSet unionSet:firstSet];
[unionFirstSecondSet unionSet:secondSet];

NSLog(@"Merged %@",unionFirstSecondSet);
```

---

Using `Dictionary`

```
NSMutableDictionary *mergeDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:firstArray forKeys:firstArray];
for (id element in secondArray) {
    [mergeDict setObject:element forKey:element];
}
NSArray *mergedArray=[mergeDict allKeys];

NSLog(@"Merged %@",mergedArray);
```

---

Using some array API tweaks

```
NSMutableArray *mergedArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:firstArray];
[mergedArray addObjectsFromArray:secondArray];
for (id object in secondArray) {
    [mergedArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:object];
}
[mergedArray addObjectsFromArray:secondArray];

NSLog(@"Merged %@",mergedArray);
```

Comment: Superb answer with description +1..

Comment: None of your solutions produces the desired result (the order is always wrong). The third and especially the fourth are just utter nonsense. Why do people upvote this kind of answer?

Comment: Ok You want me to use NSOrderedSet? Yes I can do thatone also... but i prefered 1 and 2. rest are just for fun? If you want to downvote my each and every answer you are welcome... go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableSet * wants = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:firstArray];
NSMutableSet * union = [[NSMutableSet setWithArray:secondArray] unionSet:wants];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[union allObjects]];
```

Comment: using of union is showing error(expected identifier)

Comment: union might be a keyword -- change it to custom name